# PayPal Transaction Search API - What does T0015 Event Code mean?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

We are working on an integration with PayPal's Transaction Search API. [Official documentation here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/transaction-search/transaction-event-codes/).

Regarding T0015 event code which as per the docs means - "Third Party Payout".
The question is:

- Is this representing a payout for a merchant from PayPal account to a Bank account?
- What does "*Third Party"* mean? Does it imply PayPal being a third party processor/gateway for a transaction between customer and merchant?
- Or does it mean a payout made through a third party API? If so are there any examples to better understand this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The section is PayPal to PayPal transactions, has nothing to do with a banks. As a general matter, a payout from a third party is someone (a third party) sending you money from their account, as a [payout action](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/) rather than as a purchase action.

If you need specifics about that event code you should contact PayPal.